# Regex building Help required

Tags: regex

I need help in regular expression building that include html tags, repeated patterns etc at http://regex101.com/r/iD3xT7/1

I have done part of it already but when I want to repeat the pattern for `<a\s[^<>]*>([^<>]*)<\/a>\s` it gets failed for ***repetition***. Just like *recursive*. I need complete pattern for this.

Comment: What are you trying to extract ?

Comment: Don't use regex for matching HTML. What happens if you use `<a href="" alt="6 > 3">Foo</a>`? Suddenly it would think that the content is `3">Foo`.

Comment: for match 3 I need 'Action'

Comment: [..that being said, this is not about repetition. It's about you having to use the `global` flag.](http://regex101.com/r/iD3xT7/2)

Comment: I need whole pattern not only for hyperlinks

Comment: Is there a special reason you want to use regular expressions? Because (as @h2ooooooo pointed out) there are other better ways to match HTML.

Comment: I am open to any other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning: you shouldn't use regex for HTML parsing,

as it have already been said many times on SO.**

---

That said, you won't be able to repeat the hyperlink pattern only.

For better clarity, you should extract each kind of data with it own regex. Example in PHP:

```
$html = /* choose your way to retrieve the HTML */;
$movie = array();

preg_match('/Released:.*?<td>(.+?)<\/td>/s', $html, $matches);
$movies['lucy']['released'] = $matches[1];

preg_match('/Runtime:.*?<td>(.+?)<\/td>/s', $html, $matches);
$movies['lucy']['runtime'] = $matches[1];

preg_match_all('/<a[^>]*?genre[^>]*?>(.+?)<\/a>/', $html, $matches);
$movies['lucy']['genres'] = $matches[1];

var_dump($movies);
/*
array(1) {
  ["lucy"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["released"]=>
    string(13) "July 25, 2014"
    ["runtime"]=>
    string(8) "90 mins "
    ["genres"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Action"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Sci-Fi"
    }
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: Could you be able to explain the pattern <a[^>]*?genre[^>]*?>(.+?)<\/a> and what is the difference between this and html parsing.

Comment: It is HTML parsing. [This page](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%3Ca%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3Fgenre%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3F%3E(.%2B%3F)%3C%5C%2Fa%3E%2F) will helps you to understand the pattern.